# How to use Myblock parameters on EV3?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

How do I use them? What do they do? How do they work? I have no idea, and would like some information on them.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see the following tutorials (found by searching for "mindstorms ev3 parameter"), and edit your question if you can narrow it down to a concrete question. https://stemrobotics.cs.pdx.edu/node/3357 https://education.lego.com/en-us/lessons/ev3-tutorials/basics-configuring-blocks

Comment: I meant parameters on Myblocks. Should have specified.